# Expectation Claim for Random Variable based on maximum operation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, algorithms, random-variables, expected-value

I have been reading about some randomized algorithms and I appear to be having an issue reproducing what should be a very simple claim, while the rest of the analysis is clear.

Suppose we are given the keys $k \in \lbrace 1, \cdots, n\rbrace$ and we define the random variables $X_k$ to be the number of times we flip heads without seeing tails, using a fair coin so $P[heads] = \frac{1}{2}$, indexed by the value $k$. Let us then define the random variable $\bar{X} = \max_{k} X_k$.

For some $k$, the probability that $X_k$ is at least as big as some value $m$ corresponds to the probability of flipping heads $m$ times in a row, so clearly $P[X_k \geq m] = \frac{1}{2^m}$. If we turn our attention to finding the probability that $\bar{X} \geq m$ for some $m$, we know this will be true as long as at least one value for $k$ exists such that $X_k \geq m$. Thus, $P[\bar{X} \geq m] = P\left[\bigvee_{i=k}^n (X_k \geq m)\right]$. We can use union bound to show that $P\left[\bigvee_{i=k}^n (X_k \geq m)\right] \leq \sum_{k=1}^n P[X_k \geq m] = \frac{n}{2^m}$. This is cool to know because now we can choose $m = c \log n$ and find that $P[\bar{X} \geq c \log n] \leq \frac{1}{n^{c-1}}$, implying that $\bar{X}$ is bounded by $O(\log n)$ in high probability, given a choice for $c > 1$.

My issue is when I then go to try and find the expectation of $\bar{X}$. I have found a claim that says $(1)$ holds.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] &= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P[\bar{X} \geq m] \tag{1}
\end{align}

I cannot find a way to go from the standard expectation definition in $(2)$ to obtain the claim $(1)$.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} m P[\bar{X} = m] \tag{2}
\end{align}

I was thinking about something along the lines of

\begin{align}
P[\bar{X} = m] &= P[\bar{X} \geq m \wedge \bar{X} < m+1] \\
&= P[\bar{X} < m+1 | \bar{X} \geq m] P[\bar{X} \geq m]
\end{align}

but I cannot resolve what the conditional probability term should be, so I feel this is a bad direction. Expression $(1)$ seems to imply that the conditional probability is $\frac{1}{m}$ for a given $m$, but I do not see how to get there.

The analysis of the expectation, given $(1)$ is true, leads to the fact that $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] \leq \log n + 2$, which is quite interesting in contrast to the high probability bound. Given $(1)$, the analysis makes sense, but I just cannot see how to arrive at $(1)$. Can anyone help? I feel I am missing something obvious.

Comment: If $Z$ is a nonnegative integer random variable then $$Z = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1_{\{Z\geq n\}} \implies E[Z] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E[1_{\{Z\geq n\}}] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }P[Z\geq n]$$ where $1_A$ is an indicator function that is 1 if event $A$ is true and 0 else. In general if $Z$ is a nonnegative random variable then $E[Z] = \int_0^{\infty} P[Z\geq t]dt$.

Comment: @Michael Interesting idea which basically means we can just use indicator random variables, i.e. define $Z_n = 1_{\lbrace \bar{X} \geq n\rbrace}$ and note that $\bar{X} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Z_n$ and use this representation to compute the expectation. Makes a lot of sense. Do you see this as the only clear way to produce the expression in $(1)$? It is certainly easy enough.

Comment: This is the easiest way(it is standard). You can also get the integral formula by integration by parts (or summation by parts for sums) but there is a tricky part of showing a tail term goes to zero. Fubini Tonelli ensures we can always pass an expectation through a sum or integral of nonnegative random variables.

Comment: @Michael: interesting comment about the integration by parts note. I will stick to the standard way; thank you for enlightening me!